# What are the conditions for molecular,photon resonance other than same frequency?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, resonance

I know that the basic condition for molecular,photon resonance is same frequency but what are the other condition for this process like phase relationship,round trip of the molecules and so.Also can you please link a complete theory behind this process